# Can boost iostreams read and compress gzipped files on the fly?

Tags: c++, gzip, boost-iostreams

I am reading a gzipped file using boost iostreams:
The following works fine:

```
 namespace io = boost::iostreams;
  io::filtering_istream in;
  in.push(boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<>());
  in.push(io::file_source("test.gz"));
  stringstream ss;
  copy(in, ss);
```

However, I don't want to take the memory hit of reading an entire gzipped file
into memory. I want to be able to read the file incrementally.

For example, if I have a data structure X that initializes itself from istream,

```
X x;
x.read(in);
```

fails. Presumably this is because we may have to put back characters into the stream
if we are doing partial streams. Any ideas whether boost iostreams supports this?

Comment: Would doing an operation such as calling `getline()` then `compressing()` it through a loop work for you?

Comment: @user99545: No: because X creates itself from binary data.

Comment: I don't see why not. I've used boost iostreams to read and write zlib-compressed streams in this manner.

Comment: Does this answer the question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688296/how-to-decompress-gzipstream-with-zlib

Answer (score 1):

According to the [iostream documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) the type `boost::io::filtering_istream` derives from `std::istream`. That is, it should be possible to pass this everywhere an `std::istream&` is expected. If you have errors at run-time because you need to `unget()` or `putback()` characters you should have a look at the `pback_size` parameter which specifies how many characters are return at most. I haven't seen in the documentation what the default value for this parameter is.

If this doesn't solve your problem can you describe what your problem is exactly? From the looks of it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write your own filter. For instance, to read a .tar.gz and output the files contained, I wrote something like

```
//using namespace std;
namespace io = boost::iostreams;

struct tar_expander
{
    tar_expander() : out(0), status(header)
    {
    }
    ~tar_expander()
    {
        delete out;
    }

    /* qualify filter */
    typedef char char_type;
    struct category :
        io::input_filter_tag,
        io::multichar_tag
    { };

    template<typename Source>
    void fetch_n(Source& src, std::streamsize n = block_size)
    {
           /* my utility */
           ....
    }

    // Read up to n filtered characters into the buffer s,
    // returning the number of characters read or -1 for EOF.
    // Use src to access the unfiltered character sequence
    template<typename Source>
    std::streamsize read(Source& src, char* s, std::streamsize n)
    {
      fetch_n(src);
      const tar_header &h = cast_buf<tar_header>();
      int r;

      if (status == header)
      {
          ...
      }
      std::ofstream *out;
      size_t fsize, stored;

      static const size_t block_size = 512;
      std::vector<char> buf;

      enum { header, store_file, archive_end } status;
   }
}
```

My function `read(Source &...)` when called receives the unzipped text.
To use the filter:

```
ifstream file("/home/..../resample-1.8.1.tar.gz", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
io::filtering_streambuf<io::input> in;
in.push(tar_expander());
in.push(io::gzip_decompressor());
in.push(file);
io::copy(in, cout);
```