# How to decompress gzipstream with zlib

Tags: c++, compression, zlib

Can someone tell me which function I need to use in order to decompress a byte array that has been compressed with vb.net's gzipstream. I would like to use zlib.

I've included the zlib.h but I haven't been able to figure out what function(s) I should use.

Answer (score 8):

You can take a look at [The Boost Iostreams Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>

std::ifstream file;
file.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
file.open(filename, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);

boost::iostreams::filtering_stream<boost::iostreams::input> decompressor;
decompressor.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
decompressor.push(file);
```

And then to decompress line by line:

```
for(std::string line; getline(decompressor, line);) {
    // decompressed a line
}
```

Or entire file into an array:

```
std::vector<char> data(
      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(decompressor)
    , std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
    );
```

Comment: thank you, and how do I do that with an byte array stored in `char *`

Comment: @Lotzki See "Or entire file into an array:" example.

Comment: @Lotzki If you are unsure what `vector` is, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `inflateInit2()` to request gzip decoding.  Read the documentation in [zlib.h](http://zlib.net/manual.html).

There is a lot of sample code in the [zlib distribution](http://zlib.net/current/zlib.tar.gz).  Also take a look at [this heavily documented example of zlib usage](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html).  You can modify that one to use `inflateInit2()` instead of `inflateInit()`.

Comment: I've been trying to understand the documentation for hours...I just don't understand it. In vb.net it took me 10 minutes, I don't know why I'm having so much trouble with this one. 
How do I convert my `char *` to the correct stream in order to call `inflateInit2()`? And how do I get the output as `char *` ? Isn't there any simple example code?

Comment: You don't need to convert anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C function that does the job with zlib:

```
int gzip_inflate(char *compr, int comprLen, char *uncompr, int uncomprLen)
{
    int err;
    z_stream d_stream; /* decompression stream */

    d_stream.zalloc = (alloc_func)0;
    d_stream.zfree = (free_func)0;
    d_stream.opaque = (voidpf)0;

    d_stream.next_in  = (unsigned char *)compr;
    d_stream.avail_in = comprLen;

    d_stream.next_out = (unsigned char *)uncompr;
    d_stream.avail_out = uncomprLen;

    err = inflateInit2(&d_stream, 16+MAX_WBITS);
    if (err != Z_OK) return err;

    while (err != Z_STREAM_END) err = inflate(&d_stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);

    err = inflateEnd(&d_stream);
    return err;
}
```

The uncompressed string is returned in uncompr. It's a null-terminated C string so you can do puts(uncompr). The function above only works if the output is text. I have tested it and it works.

Comment: Hi, i was wondering if the arguments `uncompr` and `uncomprLen` are known in advanced, or modified within the method `gzip_inflate` ? How can you know in advance the length of the uncompressed stream ? thanks

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the zlib usage example. http://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c

The function that does the real work is inflate(), but you need inflateInit() etc.