# From char* to stream

Tags: c++, compression

I want to use Byte Pair Encoding to decompress a byte array. The sourcecode (not from me) I have is using filestream to read a file byte by byte. However, I want to decompress `char *`.

I have been trying to convert this using stringstream and other things, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I would like to use it like this: `expand(char *inputarray, char *outputarray)`

I am new to c++, just switched from vb.net, so don't be too hard on me :)

This is the code:

```
/* expand.c */
/* Copyright 1994 by Philip Gage */

#include <stdio.h>

/* decompress data from input to output */
void expand (FILE *input, FILE *output)
{
  unsigned char left[256], right[256], stack[30];
  short int c, count, i, size;

  /* unpack each block until end of file */
  while (( count = getc ( input )) != EOF )
  {
    /* set left to itself as literal flag */
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 256; i++ )
    {
      left[i] = i;
    }

    /* read pair table */
    for ( c = 0 ; ; )
    {
      /* skip range of literal bytes */
      if ( count > 127 )
      {
        c += count -127;
        count = 0;
      }
      if ( c==256 )
      { 
        break;
      }

      /* read pairs, skip right if literal */
      for ( i = 0; i <= count; i++, c++ )
      {
        left[c] = getc(input);
        if ( c != left[c] )
        {
          right[c] = getc(input);
        }
      }
      if (c == 256)
      {
        break;
      }
      count = getc(input);
    }

    /* calculate packed data block size */
    size = 256 * getc(input) + getc(input);

    /* unpack data block */
    for ( i = 0 ; ; )
    {
      /* pop byte from stack or read byte */
      if ( i )
      { 
        c = stack[--i];
      }
      else
      {
        if ( !size--)
        {
          break;
        }
        c = getc(input);
      }

      /* output byte or push pair on stack */
      if ( c == left[c] )
      {
        putc(c, output);
      }
      else
      {
        stack[i++] = right[c];
        stack[i++] = left[c];
      }
    }
  }
}

void main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  FILE *infile, *outfile;

  if ( argc != 3 )
  {
    printf("Usage: expand infile outfile\n");
  }
  else
  {
    if (( infile = fopen(argv[1],"rb"))==NULL)
    {
      printf("Error opening input %s\n",argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {  
      if ((outfile=fopen(argv[2],"wb"))==NULL)
      {
        printf("Error opening output %s\n", argv[2]);
      }
      else
      {
        expand ( infile, outfile );
        fclose ( outfile );
        fclose ( infile );
      }
    }
  }
}

/* end of file */
```

Comment: It seems that `expand` reads and writes to a file, with `ifstream` you could read the file output back into your program and go ahead that way.

Comment: this isn't C either, its garbageC (void main)

Comment: Can the "encrypted" data contain a zero byte?

Comment: [I gave you the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14688354/412080). You only need to understand that `char*` can be obtained from `vector<char>`.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin I think the question is "How to convert the `expand()` function to read from a `char *` instead of a `FILE *`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Do you mean NULL byte? Then yes. Empty, no.

Comment: Then things like `stringstream` might not be good, as it might signal end-of-file for the string terminator character.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want it to do I guess. The functions `str_getc()` and `str_putc()` are equivalent of `putc(int , FILE *)` and `getc(FILE *)`

```
int sCtr = 0, dCtr = 0;
int str_getc(char *str) { return str[sCtr++]; } //char * equivalent of getc()
void str_putc(int c, char *str) { str[dCtr++] = c; } //char * equivalent of putc()

void expand (char *input, char *output)
{
  unsigned char left[256], right[256], stack[30];
  short int c, count, i, size;

  /* unpack each block until end of file */
  while (( count = str_getc ( input )) != -1)
  {
    /* set left to itself as literal flag */
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 256; i++ )
    {
      left[i] = i;
    }

    /* read pair table */
    for ( c = 0 ; ; )
    {
      /* skip range of literal bytes */
      if ( count > 127 )
      {
        c += count -127;
        count = 0;
      }
      if ( c==256 )
      { 
        break;
      }

      /* read pairs, skip right if literal */
      for ( i = 0; i <= count; i++, c++ )
      {
        left[c] = str_getc(input);
        if ( c != left[c] )
        {
          right[c] = str_getc(input);
        }
      }
      if (c == 256)
      {
        break;
      }
      count = str_getc(input);
    }

    /* calculate packed data block size */
    size = 256 * str_getc(input) + str_getc(input);

    /* unpack data block */
    for ( i = 0 ; ; )
    {
      /* pop byte from stack or read byte */
      if ( i )
      { 
        c = stack[--i];
      }
      else
      {
        if ( !size--)
        {
          break;
        }
        c = str_getc(input);
      }

      /* output byte or push pair on stack */
      if ( c == left[c] )
      {
        str_putc(c, output);
      }
      else
      {
        stack[i++] = right[c];
        stack[i++] = left[c];
      }
    }
  }
}


/* end of file */
```

Comment: this looks very promising, I will report back with the results later today!

Comment: alright, @Lotzki, if you can give me a test string, and the expected output string, I can set up an IDEONE run for this program.

Comment: You should probably add a note that the global index variables needs to be reset if this function is to be used multiple times. And since this is supposed to be C++, you could pass the pointers by reference and modify them directly instead, thereby eliminating the need for the global indexes.

Comment: agreed @JoachimPileborg, you are free to edit the answer if you wish to.

Comment: @Aniket I have tried it, however the app crashes. I compressed the string `testestest`. The output was `FE 7F FD FF 73 00 74 65 00 04 FE FE FE`. When i tried to decompress it with the edited expand function the application crashes

Comment: @Lotzki, what was your main function like?

Comment: @Lotzki, if you're using a C++ compiler, then I think, changing the `char *` to `std::string` would not hurt.

Comment: This is my main `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 char *infile, *outfile;
 infile = ReadResource(); //This returns the compressed char * included in the resource, printf(infile) works.
 printf(infile);
 expand(infile, outfile);
 printf(outfile);
 
}`

Thanks for your advide...like I said, I am new to c/c++ :)

Comment: @Aniket Do you know how to print the `char *` as hex code? I would like to test if there is any problem with `ReadResource()`

Comment: @Lotzki, the problem is with `expand()` function. I am debugging it to see what could be wrong

Comment: Thank you, I wont' be able to respond in the next 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

All C++ input streams have a [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) function that can be used to get one character at a time. And output streams have a corresponding [`put`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put) function.

Simply replace where needed.

Of course, the normal input and output operators `>>` and `<<` can be used as well.

---

If you want to work on the arrays directly, that's easy as well, once you learn how to handle pointers. Then just pass the input and output arrays to the function, and when getting a byte use e.g. `left[c] = *input++;` and when writing use e.g. `*output++ = c;`.

---

You can also use a standard C++ container such as [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for storage of the data. In this case you use e.g. `std::vector<char>`, and use iterators to get and set single characters.

---

This is all actually very basic stuff, and things you should learn yourself quickly. Just read more about pointers, arrays, the C++ [standard I/O functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io), and the [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: error compiling, `void main`, C++ does not allow `void` return type for main function.

Comment: @Aniket Yes, but it's unrelated to the question.

Comment: I know, i already changed it to `int main` and added `return 0`...then it works