# Subshell redirection like operation in c++?

Tags: c++

I am using a c++ library that takes a file path, not a file handle or descriptor. I currently run my program as

```
./my_prog path_to_file
```

where `path_to_file` is the filename I will pass to the library. These files are often gzipped, and so I need to have a wrapper program that does something like

```
./my_prog <(zcat path_to_gzipped_file)
```

when the file is gzipped. What are some good options for doing that same sort of operation, but inside c++, i.e. in c++, I determine if the file is gzipped (I'm happy to just check the file extension), create something like a named pipe whose other end is connected to `zcat` and pass in the name of the pipe to the library?

Comment: http://www.zlib.net/

Comment: Looks like boost also has support for gzip decompression: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688296/how-to-decompress-gzipstream-with-zlib

Comment: The problem that I have is that I need to pass in a filename to the library. I'm not reading the file myself.